# ошибка в makefile . Makefile:24: *** пропущен разделитель. Останов

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile

```
# Имя вашего исполняемого файла
TARGET = my_program

# Файлы исходного кода
SOURCES = MK_1.cpp

# Файлы заголовочного кода
HEADERS = MK.h

# Файлы объектного кода (автоматически получат расширение .o)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

# Компилятор
CXX = g++

# Флаги компиляции
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall

# Цель по умолчанию (сборка всего)
all: $(TARGET)

# Линковка объектных файлов в исполняемый файл
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
 $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET)

# Компиляция каждого cpp файла в объектный код
%.o: %.cpp $(HEADERS)
 $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# Очистка сгенерированных файлов
clean:
 rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)

.PHONY: all clean
```

Comment: символ табуляции там должна быть, а не пробелы.

Comment: имеете ввиду "/n"?

Comment: по возможности покажи как следует , буду очень благодарен

Comment: Табуляция - это `/t`. На клавиатуре клавиша "Tab" называется.

Comment: В Makefile вместо отступов пробелами нужно делать отступ табами. В vscode в самом низу справа жмете "Tab Size", выбираете "Indent Using Tabs". Ну и заменяете все отступы на табы (через то же меню настройки табов можно сделать автоматическую конвертацию через "Convert Indentation To Tabs").